# jQuery UI Accordion Can't Open 3rd Panel Programatically

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Having trouble getting the 3rd panel in a Jquery UI Accordion to open via a jQuery program call, while keeping panels 1 and 2 closed. My HTML structure is like this:

```
<div class="accordion1">
<div class="left-menu-title" id="restaurant">
  <h3>Restaurant</h3>
</div>
<div class="left-menu clickable" id="nav-restaurant">
  <div id="cat_581274_divs">
    <ul id="nav_581274">
      <li><a href="/reservations">reservations</a></li>
      <li><a href="/menus">menus</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="left-menu-title" id="bakery">
  <h3>Bakery</h3>
</div>
<div class="left-menu clickable" id="nav-bakery">
  <div id="cat_581276_divs">
    <ul id="nav_581276">
      <li><a href="/pastry-chef">our pastry chef</a></li>
      <li><a href="/bakery-menu">bakery menu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="left-menu-title" id="wine">
  <h3>Wine Shop</h3>
</div>
<div class="left-menu clickable" id="nav-wine">
  <div id="cat_581280_divs">
    <ul id="nav_581280">
      <li><a href="/wine-shop">about our wine shop</a></li>
      <li><a href="/wine-tastings">wine tastings &amp; events</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

My accordian is initialized with:

```
$(".accordion1").accordion({ header: ".left-menu-title" });
```

and it works great. I am trying to programatically open the 3rd #wine Wine Shop panel with the Restaurant and Bakery panels closed, but when I use any of these ALL the panels open instead of just the 3rd:

```
$('.accordion1').accordion('activate', 2 );
```

doesn't work nor does

```
$('.accordion1').accordion('activate', 'div#wine');
```

nor does

```
$('.accordion1').accordion('activate', 'div#wine h3');
```

nor does

```
$('.accordion1').accordion('activate', '#nav-wine');
```

Obviously doing something wrong. Using jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js and jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: works for me (both your first and second methods), see http://jsfiddle.net/ZHQuH/1/ which uses older versions of both jquery and jqueryui, and http://jsfiddle.net/ZHQuH/ uses the newest of both. check that you're running the code in an appropriate place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run them in order, like so:

```
$(".accordion1").accordion({ header: ".left-menu-title" });
$('.accordion1').accordion('activate', 2 );
```

See it in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/WWPFq/

Comment: you are correct, it works on my page too. I didn't think of running the first line to reinitialize the accordion again since it was already running ok on the page and I was sending the second command to activate 2 as a later event. But the secret was sending both lines together again, even if the accordion is already up and running.

Comment: You can see the working jQuery accordion on [link((http://www.murphys-atlanta-restaurant.com) on the subpages. The accoridon on the home page is slightly different code.